# How many numbers can we store with 1 bit?

Tags: byte, bit

I want to know how many characters or numbers can I store in 1 bit only. It will be more helpful if you tell it in octal, hexadecimal.

Comment: There are 8 bits in a byte. You can't store anything other than a `1` or a `0` in a bit, so you can store 2 different numbers in a bit (but not at the same time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know how many characters or numbers can I store in 1 bit only.

It is not *practical* to use a single bit to store numbers or characters.  However, you could say:

- One integer provided that the integer is in the range 0 to 1.
- One ASCII character provided that the character is either NUL (0x00) or SOH (0x01).

The bottom line is that a single bit has two states: 0 and 1.  Any *value domain* with more that two values in the domain cannot be represented using a single bit.

> It will be more helpful if you tell it in octal, hexadecimal.

That is not relevant to the problem.  Octal and hexadecimal are different *textual* representations for numeric data.  They make no difference to the meaning of the numbers, or (in most cases<sup>1</sup>) the way that you represent the numbers in a computer.

---

<sup>1 - The exception is when you are representing numbers as text; e.g. when you represent the number 42 in a text document as the character '4' followed by the character '2'.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A bit is a "binary digit", or a value from a set of size two. If you have one or more bits, you raise 2 to the power of the number of bits. So, 2¹ gives 2. The field in Mathematics is called [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).